# Bootstrap wrapping buttons not aligned

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have set of buttons aligned fine on desktop but on mobile, when buttons wraps, second row sticks with first set of buttons and starts a little inside.

Please see following fiddle for the problem;
https://jsfiddle.net/u4dq9x38/

HTML:

```
<div role="toolbar" class="btn-toolbar bottom-buffer">
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="">
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></span>
        Button
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="">
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></span>
        Button
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="">
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></span>
        Button
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="">
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></span>
        Button
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="">
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></span>
        Button
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="">
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></span>
        Button
    </a>
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="">
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></span>
        Button
    </a>
</div>
```

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: maybe so https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/wcju61r0/ or https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/kwd2jh96/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `btn-toolbar` class, seems like it adds a space before the first element, so not designed to work for wrapping

You may need to add a bottom and right margin to each button individually

Comment: Looks better know, and looks like I need to add bottom margin class to each button manually?

Answer (score 0):

```css
/* Latest compiled and minified CSS included as External Resource*/

/* Optional theme */
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');

body {
    margin: 10px;
}
.btn-toolbar>.btn:nth-child(1){
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div role="toolbar" class="btn-toolbar bottom-buffer">
              <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></span>
            Button
        </a>
     <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></span>
            Button
        </a>
     <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></span>
            Button
        </a>
     <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></span>
            Button
        </a>
     <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></span>
            Button
        </a>
     <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></span>
            Button
        </a>
     <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="">
            <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></span>
            Button
        </a>
    </div>
```